# $(this).val() in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In jquery I use

```
$(this).val();

$(".input").change(function(){
      $(this).val('any value');
})
```

What is the angular equivalent? I want to put a value in an input text, without typing $scope.input=xxx.

I want to have a function, in which I can assign a value to the text field that has the ng-change event

http://jsfiddle.net/vhr42a19/

Comment: Generally you don't interact with elements directly with angular. So any solution that lets you do exactly that likely isn't a good one.

Comment: You would set the value to the model property to which that input is bound.

Comment: @David  want to have a function, in which I can assign a value to the text field that has the ng-change event

Comment: There is no equivalent function in Angular, because using selectors would couple the model with the view. Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/5743988).

Comment: HTML:

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type='text' ng-model='name'  ng-click="myFunction()">
</div>

JS:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.name = 'Akif';
  }
}

Answer (score 3):

You don't update the *input*, you update the *model* to which the input is bound.  Given the input you have:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type='text' ng-model='input' ng-click="myFunction('some value')">
</div>
```

This is bound to the `input` property on the model.  As a simple example, that's a property on `$scope`.  So you set that property to whatever you like, and then in your function you update it.  Something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.input = 1;
   $scope.myFunction = function(value) {
        $scope.input = value;
  }
}
```

So the controller sets an initial default for the `input` value (which should probably have a better name) as `1`.  Then when your `ng-click` event invokes `myFunction` it can pass it a new value.  [Observe](http://jsfiddle.net/vhr42a19/1/).

Comment: What I am thinking is ng-click will be occur once on clicking on the input field, if you want to change the value by typing you should use like onchange or onkeyup type events.. BTW I am new in angularjs society :)

Comment: @david  Then I should do this: n times? For each input.

   $scope.myFunction = function (value) {
         $scope.input1 = value;
   }       $scope.myFunction2 = function (value) {
         $scope.input2 = value;
   }

Comment: @yavg No, you can reuse the same model for each element that needs to have it. In that case you'd want to avoid using `$scope` and instead use a [component](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03).

Comment: @4castle  can you help me? I have created an example with what I understand. http://jsfiddle.net/6qyv8vyd/  mi idea is use a function for any input text. similar to $(".input").change(function(){
      $(this).val('any value');
})

Comment: @yavg: It's not really clear what you're necessarily trying to accomplish here.  These `input` and `myFunction` things are very contrived examples with no context.  If you have genuinely *separate* operations then you would create separate functions for them.  But it's not clear to me what your actual operations are here.

Comment: @David i need this.. $(".input").change(function(){
      $(this).val('any value');
})   but in angular.js.   Any value that has this class, modifies its value. i need this in angular.js

Comment: @yavg: Take a step back for a minute.  Stop trying to convert jQuery to AngularJS line by line, they are *very* different tools which do *very* different things.  In your overall application, in the context of that page, with DOM elements bound to a backing model, what are you trying to accomplish?  Direct line-by-line conversion isn't going to work, the tools are too different.  If you want to "use AngularJS like jQuery" then just use jQuery.

Comment: @yavg: Taking a bit of a guess on the intended functionality, is this what you're looking for?:  http://jsfiddle.net/6qyv8vyd/1/

Comment: @David Okay, david. I thank you and understand what you tell me. I would understand the logic much better if you help me do what I need. How would you do it? Use the same function to assign a value to some input text

http://jsfiddle.net/LtL0guqn/

Comment: @David I've seen your code, but I think I tangled a little what I want to do XD.